# Import Data from Powershell object into Excel Spreadhseet

Tags: excel, powershell

I have built a powershell object in a script.  In this same script I need to take that object (or parts of it) and load them into an Excel spreadsheet.  The excel spreadsheet is already saved and has headers.  I am able to find my .xlsx file, open it, save and close but not sure how to actually get my object into the file.  This script will be run a lot so ultimately I need the data to just append to the first available/empty row.

Here is the script that is opening the excel file:

```
$excel_file_path = 'C:\Users\ME\Documents\Test\SFTPTest.xlsx'
# Instantiate the COM Object
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Application.Visible = $true
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$ExcelWorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excel_file_path)
$ExcelWorkSheet = $Excel.Worksheets.item("SFTPTransfers")
$ExcelWorksheet.activate() | Out-Null
```

The headers in my excel spreadsheet are on row 1 and there are 9 columns (A-I)

My PS Object is a large oject converted from a JSON object.  I only need 9 properties of this object to go into this spreadsheet. For example, I have a property called Object1.ServerName that needs to go into the my excel file under ServerName column...etc.

Comment: An alternative approach: pipe your JSON object to Export-csv, and let excel convert the csv file to a spreadsheet..

Comment: I like this idea and actually considered it.  The only reason I don't think it will work (correct me if I'm wrong) but the person I'm doing this for doesn't want the entire object into a spreadsheet just certain properties of the object.

Comment: I was thinking about creating a smaller object from my PSObject and then doing an Export-csv on that but I feel like there might be an easier way to just write to each column in the already existing spreadsheet

Comment: You can combine `Export-Csv` with `Select-Object` to select which properties are output to the CSV. Add a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) json that is representative of your data and we can help. Writing to Excel is doable but introduces additional unnecessary complexities (i.e. ways for things to break)

Comment: I completely agree.  So the only other catch to doing an Export-csv on the JSON object itself is that there are 2 things that need exported into this spreadsheet that do not come from the JSON Object.  They come from an array that was created earlier in the script.  So I just built a new object that has all 9 columns of data ready to be exported.   It is a New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList.  Can I just do an Export-Csv on this?